# "There seem to be" vs. "There seems to be"

Tags: usage

Are the following two sentences both correct? Which one sounds more natural? I search both *There seem to be* and *There seems to be* in Google books and both generate a lot of search results.

- There seem to be so many rules and regulations these days.
- There seems to be so many rules and regulations these days.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/132752/there-seem-or-there-seems-usage-of-the-word-seem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one is correct.  You would say, "There seems to be a hurricane coming" because "hurricane" is singular and "seems" goes with singular items.  You would say, "There seem to be many hurricanes these days" because "many hurricanes" is plural and "seem" goes with plural items.